# Linux Pipeline and File Descriptor: Why do we close file descriptors of a pipeline before exec()?

Tags: c, operating-system, pipeline

I am reading MIT's XV6 book and come across following code:

```
int p[2];
char *argv[2];
argv[0] = "wc";
argv[1] = 0;
pipe(p);
if (fork() == 0)
{
    close(0);
    dup(p[0]);
    close(p[0]);
    close(p[1]);
    exec("/bin/wc", argv);
}
else
{
    close(p[0]);
    write(p[1], "hello world\n", 12);
    close(p[1]);
}
```

And I am particularly confused by `close(p[0])` and `close(p[1])` in the child process. From what I understand, `close(0)` release file descriptor used by STDOUT and dup(p[0]) copies it into the read side of the pipe, but why do we have to call `close(0)` before executing another process? I mean, if that file descriptor is closed, will the process be able to recognize where to read from? And does remove `close(0)` make any difference?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: A program expects to have 3 file descriptors open when it starts.  If you do not close the pipes, then the process will still have them open when the new program begins executing.  It's not strictly necessary to close them in this case (`wc` isn't going to do anything with the open descriptors), but it's good practice.  Once you've wasted 10s (1000s?) of hours tracking down bugs caused by file descriptors being left open, you will appreciate the value of ensuring they are closed when no longer needed.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you for your response, and I understand that closing file descriptor is necessary, but I'd like to know if closing it before exec() would have any bad effect? Would the process executed using exec() still able to redirect to file pointed by ```fd[0]```?

Comment: A new process is not started by `exec`.  It is the same process, running a new program.  It will be able to access the file descriptor that was left open, unless the "close on exec" flag was set.  By default, file descriptors opened via `pipe` do not have that flag set.